# Can I put PC hardware in a MacBook Pro case?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

I would like a **MacBook Pro**, but they are so dang expensive!!! I already have a pretty nice **Samsung Series 3 64-bit**, and I have considered Hackintosh. Hackintosh however, does not include that slick outer shell, Force Touch Trackpad, and gorgeous Retina display. **My possible solution: A pc with a mac barebone and hackintosh!!!!**

If I purchase a replacement bottom shell, top case (includes trackpad keyboard, and mic), and a complete display for Macbook Pro 13 in Retina Display 2012 (Model # A1502) the total cost would be around **$458.52**- that's saving me a whopping $741!!!

Can I put my PC components into it, **assuming they are the same type**, the replacement components, then install Hackintosh and work???

The main worry here is **if the logic board has to be genuine apple** vs my current pc one fitting, this mainly being because a replacement logic board at used to its crappiest state is $436.46

(sorry if i went overboard w/ the **bold**)

Comment: If you are considering my answer as final, please mark it as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The answer is simply No. Most Apple hardwares are custom designed for specific MBP. You cannot replace them with normal PC parts as they are generic. The PC parts are not custom designed. They are made to fit a wide range of common PC laptops.

Comment: How about 3rd party replacements such as Crucial Products??

Comment: @Madelyn It's just not going to work. Whatever money you want to use buying parts to turn your PC into a makeshift Mac would really be better spend towards buying a MacBook Pro, especially since you could probably get a deal on a used one that's a couple of years old.

Answer (score 0):

You would half to modify the connection for the screen and touchpad to fit windows laptop motherboard if you up for the challenge you could try something similar to how people put MacBook motherboard into a clamshell Mac shell